# ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 15) are incompatible

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-22a07601ab58> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 cnn_model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=64, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1338, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1322, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1303, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1081, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1139, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/losses.py", line 142, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/losses.py", line 268, in call  **
return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/losses.py", line 2122, in categorical_crossentropy
        return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/backend.py", line 5560, in categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 15) are incompatible
```

I want to apply the CNN model:

```
# For example, let's define and train a simple CNN using TensorFlow/Keras as an example:
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# Modify the output layer for multi-class classification
num_classes = 15  # Number of classes in your problem

# Assuming you have a Sequential model
cnn_model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)),
    layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')  # Use softmax for multi-class classification
])

# Compile the model
cnn_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

cnn_model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=64, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

It gives me an error at `cnn_model.fit()`.

Comment: Is your question why (None, 1) and (None, 15) are incompatible shapes?

Comment: What happens if you change `num_classes = 15` to `num_classes = 1`?

Comment: What is the shape of your `y_train` and `y_test`?